# Getting an Integer value of a Particular Intent Flag

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Every intent have an int value in android,
How I can get all int values of all intent flags.

For example, I have a flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** when i will make an apk then the **integer value of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** will be copied.
So where i can get all integer values of all flags.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need integer values but check the definition  of `android.content.Intent` class which defines the intent constants. It has all the integer values defined as hexadecimals. Please note that, ideally, your code should not make assumption about hidden details of a class (like values of constants!).